# How to examine the ID of a thread using a lot of CPU's for Mac OSX

Tags: mac-osx, central-processing-unit

In Linux, I can confirm the CPU rate of use of the thread level by a top -H -b command, 
but do not seem to support a -H -b option by the top command of Mac OSX.

How to examine the ID of a thread using a lot of CPU's for Mac OSX?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ps -aux at the command line will quickly get you the resource information fro all threads running. you could pipe it into a grep command for specifics.

ps -aux |grep myPID

Comment: Thank you for answering , but I want to sort cpu rate like a top command

Comment: Ah ok - can you run top interactively, or does it have to be in batch mode? ie within top, type o and set the key to be cpu?

Comment: Tanks a lot "top -o cpu  "  is OK! Are there Another answers?